# "Encryption support not enabled" when using snmptrap.exe

Tags: windows, snmp, snmp-trap

I have windows 10 pro. I am trying to use snmptrap.exe to send out an SNMP trap. V2c traps work fine. I get errors when I try to send out v3 traps.

Partial command line:

```
snmptrap.exe -m ALL -M "C:/Program Files/Hitachi/Protector/bin\..\db\config\mibs" -v3 -n "" -a SHA -A mypassword -x AES -X mypassword -l authPriv -u traptest -e 0x8000000001020308 localhost:163 ""
```

When I try DES, I get

```
Encryption support not enabled. (3)
```

When I try AES, I get

```
Invalid privacy protocol specified after -3x flag: AES
```

Not sure where to begin. Haven't been able to find anything helpful online.

Comment: When I change "AuthPriv" to "AuthNoPriv", the error message goes away. I still don't see the trap.

Comment: Who made "snmptrap.exe"? Ask them for support. If it is NET-SNMP, go to their site and look up the error. Google it, I saw at least 3 results that could explain it. You will need to put more effort into it to get support here...

Comment: I've tried the suggestions on net-snmp. didn't help. I believe that snmptrap is a microsoft product

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away. It is unclear why. It may have happened when I installed net-snmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that whoever built snmptrap.exe built it without encryption support. Never knew that was an option.

The stuff I found online said that this message was caused by a problem in the OS. That is what the error message meant to me. The error message is at best ambiguous and should be made more clear.